# From Google Cloud Bigtable to AWS EMR (HBase)

Tags: csv, export, hbase, amazon-emr, google-cloud-bigtable

How to export HBase table from Cloud Bigtable to AWS EMR?

I know there's an [official way](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/exporting-sequence-files) to use Google Cloud Dataflow runner for exporting HBase tables to Google Storage. But the exported file is somehow encoded that I have no way to use it except using Google Cloud Dataflow runner to import these file back to its Cloud Bigtable.

Answer (score 4):

The Cloud Bigtable sequence files should be compatible with the [HBase sequence file importer](https://hbase.apache.org/book.html#import).

Comment: Thank you very much! This is really helpful. Btw, I also found an example for using HBase's importing util: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/data_otaku/2016/12/21/working-with-the-hbase-import-and-export-utility/